# How to combine Two Select statement to One SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate Total Worked hour for the employees worked in night shift which Time In will be Yesterday evening Punched In and Time Out will be Next day Morning Punch

I tryied with two seperate simple queries and I need to get Time In & Time Out in Same Query. If any one can help with this I am glad. Below is the Two select statements which I tried need to combine

```
SELECT
EMP_Punch_Date'DATE',
MAX(EMP_Punch_Time)'TIME IN'
FROM EMP_Event_Log
WHERE EMP_Punch_Date='09-02-2018'
GROUP BY EMP_Token_No,EMP_Name,EMP_Punch_Date,EMP_Punch_Time

SELECT 
EMP_Punch_Date'DATE',
MIN(EMP_Punch_Time)'TIME OUT'
FROM EMP_Event_Log
WHERE EMP_Punch_Date='09-03-2018'
GROUP BY EMP_Token_No,EMP_Name,EMP_Punch_Date,EMP_Punch_Time
```

[image]

Comment: Simply `WHERE EMP_Punch_Date IN ('09-02-2018', '09-03-2018')`

Comment: BTW, you typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join between 2query by using sub-query

```
select max(t1.TIMEIN),min(t2.TIMEOUT),t1.DATE,t1.EMP_Token_No from
    (
    SELECT
    EMP_Punch_Date as 'DATE',
    MAX(EMP_Punch_Time) as 'TIMEIN'
    FROM EMP_Event_Log
    WHERE EMP_Punch_Date='09-02-2018'
    GROUP BY EMP_Token_No,EMP_Name,EMP_Punch_Date,EMP_Punch_Time
    ) as t1
    join
    (
    SELECT 
    EMP_Punch_Date as 'DATE',
    MIN(EMP_Punch_Time) as 'TIMEOUT'
    FROM EMP_Event_Log
    WHERE EMP_Punch_Date='09-03-2018'
    GROUP BY EMP_Token_No,EMP_Name,EMP_Punch_Date,EMP_Punch_Time
    ) t2 on t1.EMP_Token_No=t2.EMP_Token_No 
    group by t1.DATE,t1.EMP_Token_No
```

Comment: @Arrow eidted that was typo i forget to put alias for 1st query

Comment: Dear, With This Query I am getting MIN Of Each day as IN & and OUT which is not required.

Comment: @Arrow you said to combine both query i did that rest is yours query use distinct if same is multiple time return

Comment: @Arrow  41395 19:20:34.0000000 41395 2018-09-04 06:04:14.0000000 only this line?

Comment: Dear ,That What I required. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179451/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-arrow).

Comment: Dear, Its Worked Fine You saved my day. Thanks a lot. Best Regards

Comment: @Arrow if it help please accept the answer as  a SO appreciation

Answer (score 2):

If `EMP_Punch_Date` is `date` or `datetime` type.

You can try to use `BETWEEN` to combine your two query, because of there is only one difference between to query is get `MAX` or `MIN` on `EMP_Punch_Time` column.

and remove `EMP_Punch_Time` in `group by`

```
SELECT
    EMP_Punch_Date 'DATE',
    MAX(CASE WHEN EMP_Punch_Date = '09-02-2018' THEN EMP_Punch_Time END) 'TIME IN' , 
    MIN(CASE WHEN EMP_Punch_Date = '09-03-2018' THEN EMP_Punch_Time END) 'TIME OUT'
FROM EMP_Event_Log
WHERE EMP_Punch_Date BETWEEN '09-02-2018' AND '09-03-2018'
GROUP BY EMP_Token_No,EMP_Name,EMP_Punch_Date
```

Comment: This will give only MIN & MAX time in same day.

Comment: @Arrow I edit it you can try it. if that didn't hit your expect could you provide some data from `EMP_Event_Log` table?

Comment: Dear, Thank you very much for trying but this gave me the result of MAX and MIN in same between two days. Which I need MAX as TIme In today and MIN as Time Out in next day Morning.

Comment: @Arrow ok I see you can use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` or `MIN` to make it.

Comment: Dear  @D-Shih, the result is showing in two different rows as below.DATE TIME IN TIME OUT
2018-09-04 19:11:37.0000000 NULL
2018-09-05 NULL 09:57:45.0000000